# Finding the "level of black" in a pixel in a grayscale image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to calculate the percentage of black a pixel is. For example, let's say I have a pixel that is 75% black, so a gray. I have the RGBA values, so how do I get the level of black?

I have already completed getting each pixel and replacing it with a new RGBA value, and tried to use some RGBA logic to no avail.

```
#Gradient Testing here
from PIL import Image
picture = Image.open("img1.png")

img = Image.open('img1.png').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')

# Get the size of the image

width, height = picture.size

# Process every pixel

for x in range(width):
   for y in range(height):

       #Code I need here
       r1, g1, b1, alpha = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
       r,g,b = 120, 140, 99
       greylvl = 1 - (alpha(r1 + g1 + b1) / 765) #Code I tried
```

I would like to get new variable called that gives me a value, such as 0.75, which would represent a 0.75 percent black pixel.

Comment: What "RGBA logic" did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: How much "percent black" would you define that a red pixel is? (100%R, 0G, 0B, 100%A)

Comment: @mkrieger1  I tried to add up all of the rgb values and divide it by 255x3, but I got a weird collection of numbers. I can show you if you would like to see it.

Comment: If you want help with it you better show it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The image is grayscale

Comment: Does that mean that the R, G, B values are all the same?

Comment: What exactly was the problem with that code? What numbers did you expect and what did you get instead? Was there an error message (if so, please show it)?

Comment: Since you convert the image to `'LA'` format, the pixels have already be converted to levels of white, so `picture.getpixel()` will only be returning one (or possibly two if A is included) values and the first (and possibly only) one is the value you want.

Comment: P.S. Pixels in a grayscale image will be in levels of _white_, where '0' means black and `255` means white.

Comment: @martineau Your first comment is incorrect!! `picture.getpixel()` will return not return two values (1 for grey, and 1 for alpha), because we have converted `img` object into `LA` color mode, rather then the `picture` object. Even though both of them use the same image as input, but since the image object are different their won't be a mirror relationship between the operations of the two image objects. In simple words `img.getpixel()` will return a dual values tuple (as you stated) , but `picture.getpixel()` will return a tuple with values (where value = color space/mode of original image).

Comment: @Vasu Deo.S: I hedged and indicated it _might_ return two because I was unsure if it would return the alpha value or not — it's been a quite a while since I've worked with images at the pixel level with the PIL…

Comment: @martineau I think you missed my point, Let me reiterate. You stated ***`picture.getpixel()` will return one (or possibly 2, if Alpha included) values***. Here you are assuming that `picture` image object is converted into `LA` color mode. Which is not true. As it's the `img` image object, which goes through `convert('LA')` and hence, changes it's color mode to `LA`. The `picture` image object, doesn't goes through any color space conversion throughout the code. Therefore `picture.getpixel()` at any point of this code will return a tuple (values in tuple = channels in original image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the "LA" format you're trying to convert to is for; I would try "L" instead.

Try this code:  (Make sure you're using Python 3.)

```
from PIL import Image

picture = Image.open('img1.png').convert('L')
width, height = picture.size

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        value = picture.getpixel( (x, y) )
        black_level = 1 - value / 255
        print('Level of black at ({}, {}):  {} %'.format(x, y, black_level * 100))
```

Is this what you're looking for?